# Sails framework Need to fetch data from available table in database

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails framework to fetch data from a table and show it to the user, after some manupulations. The table belongs to another application, I just need to read the data from it.

I created a Model same as its available in the database along with the column names. I get an error as

**RequestError: There is already an object named 'table_Name' in the database.**

I cannot create table, is there a way around in sails

Comment: can you provides you models and where you get error please.

Comment: Change migrate to safe in ```config/model.js```. like this: ```migrate: 'safe'```